# Forcing Awesome to restart when connecting a new screen

Tags: awesome-wm, xrandr

I have some complicated screen and docking station setup and would like to automatically restart Awesome when docking and undocking.  How can I tell Awesome to do that?

I know the preferred way of doing things is to avoid restarting and using the `awful.screen.connect_for_each_screen` function, but given my configuration, I want to restart Awesome instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lua
screen.connect_signal("added", function() awesome.restart() end)
-- Perhaps you also want the following?
-- screen.connect_signal("removed", function() awesome.restart() end)
```